# Hibernate DAO Unit Testing Simple Fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, dao

I am very new to API development in Java and would like to create a proper unit test for my DAO Java class. The project uses Hibernate and the class fetches data from a MySQL database, returns it in a JSON format for a GET request.

I'm not sure how to write the unit test, if anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

```
public class LabelDAO extends AbstractDAO<LabelEntity> {

    public LabelEntity findLabelByLabelId(final String labelId) {
        final String query = "SELECT l FROM LabelEntity l WHERE l.labelId = :labelId";
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(query, LabelEntity.class).setParameter("labelId", labelId).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to test? Do you want to test the query? The request itself or the JSON format? However, you should have a constant source for the data. What happens if someone accidentally deletes that specific label you are testing?

Comment: I just wish to test the query and if it returns in LabelEntity object (if that makes sense).

Comment: Also the API is using a database with a readonly account. I think it should be fine.

Comment: Then you need to set up a normal database connection and run that query. No mocking etc. really makes sense there. And for unit tests, never test against a system that you can't 110% guarantee not to change

Comment: Oh so there is no need to create a Unit Test for this DAO?

Comment: You still want to have a unit test, but there is nothing special about it. You set up the database connection as usual and run your query and verify the result

Comment: That's the thing I'm not sure how to write that particular unit test :<

Comment: The same as you would write any other unit test, except that you don't mock but set up the usual database connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First add junit library and hamcrest

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. For test sql query I use memory database [H2](https://h2database.com/html/main.html)
   Add H2 JDBC Driver from Maven dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.214</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Use database migrations library for create mock data. I advise you use database migration library for project.
   For example [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/). I selected flyway for sample.
   Add from Maven dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.13</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

3.1 Create migration directory **src/main/resources/db/migration/test**.
3.2 Create sql script file. **V1__Create_label_table.sql** and set sql commands:

```
CREATE TABLE label (
   id bigint not null,
   name varchar(100) not null
);

INSERT INTO label (id, name) values (1, 'My label');
```

And need separately setting your entity manager for test...

Sample test:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
            .locations("classpath:/db/migration/test")
            .baselineOnMigrate(true)
            .dataSource("jdbc:h2:~/mem", "test", null)
            .load();

    flyway.clean();
    flyway.migrate();


    LabelDao labelDao = new LabelDao();
    labelDao.findLabelByLabelId("1");
    assertThat(labelDao.findLabelByLabelId("1").getName(), equalTo("My label"));

}
```

If you use **spring** you can use [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

For example:

```
public interface LabelRepository extends JpaRepository<LabelEntity, Long> {
}
```

And replace code:

```
@Service
public class LabelDao {

    @Autowired
    private LabelRepository labelRepository;

    public Optional<LabelEntity> findLabelByLabelId(final Long labelId) {
        return labelRepository.findById(labelId);
    }
}
```

Sample test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private LabelDao labelDao;

    @Test
    public void test()  {
        labelDao.findLabelByLabelId(1L);
        assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(labelDao.findLabelByLabelId(1L).orElse(null)).getName(), equalTo("My label"));
    }
}
```

Comment: for an upvote on this could you introduce JUnit test library and what your test does?

Comment: And maybe a bit more details on the assert that line